# How to convert, or parse, a string to work with dateserial VBA Excel

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have a column of data which is composed of two elements (entered as a string).

```
3/20/2016 6:30:55 PM
3/12/2016 8:15:45 PM
3/8/2016 1:25:18 AM
```

I want to set a variable to be equal to the DateSerial of the date portion of the string noted above.

I do not want to pull the data apart and have it reside in separate columns. I wish to leave the formatting intact.

I will be loading an array with all the data in the table (multiple columns) but I want the array to be indexed by date. I will run a quicksort on the array and then do some additional cross referencing with the sorted array. However, I cannot get to those stages, with the actual data set, as I'm stuck on the date issue.

How can I index by date given the format of the source data?

```
Dim d as Date
Dim arTemp
Dim arTemp1
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim list As Object, list1 As Object
Dim RowCount as Integer, y As Integer

Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList")
Set list1 = CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList")

For Each WS In WorkSheets
    With WS
        For RowCount = 7 to 207
            'Works perfectly if the data in Column 1 is actually a date
            d = DateSerial(Year(.Cells(RowCount, 1)), Month(.Cells(RowCount, 1)), 1)

                If list.Containskey(d) Then
                    arTemp = list(d) 
                    arTemp1 = list1(d)'omitted from code below but follows the same format
                Else
                    ReDim arTemp(8)
                    ReDim arTemp1(8)
                End If
                For y = 2 to 7 'Cycle through the columns and load array/list
                    arTemp(0) = arTemp(0) + .Cells(RowCount, y) 'Grab Km
                    arTemp(1) = arTemp(1) + .Cells(RowCount, y) 'Grab Route Hrs
                    arTemp(2) = arTemp(2) + .Cells(RowCount, y) 'Grab No. Deliveries
                    arTemp(3) = arTemp(3) + .Cells(RowCount, y) 'Grab No. of Del Pieces
                    arTemp(4) = arTemp(4) + .Cells(RowCount, y) 'Grab No. Pick-ups
                    arTemp(5) = arTemp(5) + .Cells(RowCount, y) 'Grab No. of PU Pieces
                    arTemp(6) = arTemp(6) + .Cells(RowCount, y) 'Grab Total Stops
                    arTemp(7) = arTemp(7) + .Cells(RowCount, y) 'Grab Total Pieces
                    arTemp(8) = arTemp(8) + 1
                    list(d) = arTemp
            'do other stuff here .........................................
            Next y
        Next RowCount
    End With
Next
```

Comment: `Split(cellValueHere, " ")(0)` will give you the date part, so you should be able to pass that to `DateSerial`

Comment: It's rarely a good idea to store date/time as string.  Why not convert the spreadsheet to date/time serial and format to display as it is now?

Comment: @ Tim Williams: I will try the split option and see how things work.
@ Chris Neilsen: Why is it a really good idea to "double" store the date and time as a single element? Also, how would I convert, as you suggest, the spreadsheet? I was trying to avoid "reformatting" the raw data as that is what the office software exports as it's report format. Other staff are unlikely to do any manual formatting and I was hoping to avoid having to "format" all future worksheets that get imported to the workbook.  Please explain in a bit more detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using DateValue() instead of DateSerial()?

Using DateValue you can simply use the code

```
DateVariable = DateValue("10/30/2016 09:18 pm")
```

And it will resolve to

```
DateVariable = 10/30/2016
```

Should be a lot simpler than trying to use DateSerial

You can then add the following line

```
DateVariable = DateVariable - Day(DateVariable) + 1
```

To get to the first of the month

Comment: @Gary'sStudent good spot - I thought I'd actually read the request thoroughly for a change, turns out not. That isn't too hard to accomodate for, I've added an extra line

Comment: ______________very nice_____________

Comment: @ danl & Gary's Student: I'll try out your suggestion. As to why I was using DateSerial, it is what I, initially, got comfortable with (I'm new to VBA) so it's essentially been my "goto" for date manipulation and indexes etc.

Comment: @WarOrdos  `DateSerial()` also avoids any quirky behavior associated with `DateValue()` 's dependence on Regional Settings.

Comment: This is very true - although if the dates are stored as text you can't necessarily win on that front, as you still have to decide whether you interpret the dates as DDMMYYYY or MMDDYYYY

Comment: I have up-voted both your answers, as both solve my particular issue. I am currently using the DateVariable option from danl, and as I am limited to selecting one, I've chosen this, as Gary also seemed impressed with your submission.

Thank-you both. I've learned a new option (danl) and a work around for a function I'm more comfortable with (Gary's Student).

Comment: Good points, from both of you re. regional settings and DDMM vs MMDD. At the moment, not proving to be an issue, but good caution to which I've taken note.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
d = DateSerial(Year(.Cells(RowCount, 1)), Month(.Cells(RowCount, 1)), 1)
```

with:

```
Dim s As String
s = .Cells(RowCount, 1)
ary = Split(s, " ")
bry = Split(ary(0), "/")
mm = CLng(bry(0))
yy = CLng(bry(2))
d = DateSerial(yy, mm, 1)
```

Comment: @ Gary's Student: Thank-you for a solution which allows the use of DateSerial. I am currently testing both answers (DateVariable and your DateSerial option to see which performs better in this situation--and trying to limit my own bias (or lack of experience if you prefer) re. DateSerial.